# NSLog showing the previous Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I want to retrieve  all the entries from core data added between two dates.I am using `NSPredicate`. As I am not getting the correct result I tried logging the date.It is showing the previous dates.After googling for a while I added

`[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` to my code.Now,Its showing correct dates but the results are still wrong.

This is the code I used.

```
NSDate *fromDate = [[self dateFormatter]dateFromString:self.fromDateField.text];
NSLog(@"%@",fromDate);
NSDate *toDate = [[self dateFormatter]dateFromString:self.toDateField.text];
NSLog(@"%@",toDate);
NSComparisonResult result = [fromDate compare:toDate];
switch (result) {
    case NSOrderedAscending:
    {
        //code
    }

- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter
{
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
if (dateFormatter == nil) 
{
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
}
   return dateFormatter;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log an NSDate object directly it will always display the tome in GMT/UTC timezone. you have to log the output of a date formatter.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:toDate]);
```

This will take your timezone in account. Or better: the timezone of the dateformatter's calendar — what is the device default if you dont change that.

Comment: yes,they are showing the correct dates now.then why am i getting the wrong results?

Comment: you are not getting wrong results:internally dates are always saved in the UTC timezone. that is all. but the calendar knows i.e. at what hour in UTC time the day in your timezone starts and tuff like that. Actually a date is just a moment in time, save as seconds ticking by. only inside a calendar it become meaningful, as the calendar defines what a day, month, year, hour minute is.

Comment: So dont set the timezone. leave it to the device.

Comment: I removed the time zone but i am still getting the wrong result.I want all the data added between two dates i am giving from date as 14th and to date as 18th.I am getting all the data but the one which is added on 18th.please help.

Comment: Probably your results are correct, you are just interpeting it wrong. Or you messed up the date during creation.

Comment: If you created the dates with gmt+0 than they are all messed up now.